# ipa archive bigger with xcode 5 then with xcode 4

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipa

hi i've noticed that when i create an archive with xcode 5 the ipa file is bigger then with xcode 4. I suspect that it is because of the 64 bit support. Since my app is not optimized for that is it possible to deactivate this? My architectures settings are **Standard architectures (armc7, armv7s)** and the **valid architectures are (arm64, armv7,armv7s)**

Comment: No, the app you build is supported for the result that Standard architectures intersect with Valid architectures. That is in your case armv7 and armv7s.

Comment: Is there a combination i can set so 64 bit will not be created? I tried removing the arm64 from valid architectures but it made no difference.

Comment: Your app doesn't have 64-bit code because the result (armv7,armv7s) intersect with (armv7,armv7s,arm64) is (armv7, armv7s).

Comment: So my App is not built for 64-bit already? Thats strange because the app binary within the ipa is much bigger then created with xcode 4. It's size is actually twice as much.

Comment: What value of Standard architectures and Valid architectures do you set with xcode4?

Comment: Xcode 4 has the same configuration as xcode 5 but within architectures it has Standard (armv7, armv7s) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) in xcode 5 it looks like this: (armv7, armv7s) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)